# How can I put an image in the middle of another element using CSS?

Tags: css, razor, frontend, blazor

I'm trying to get to something like this:

[image]

From this:

[image]

How could I do this?
I'm using Blazor for the Input.
This is my code:

```
<img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="/images/png/upload.png"/>
    <MudPaper @ondragenter="@SetDragClass" @ondragleave="@ClearDragClass" @ondragend="@ClearDragClass" Height="80%" Outlined="true" Class="@DragClass">
    <InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChanged" class="absolute mud-width-full mud-height-full overflow-hidden z-2" style="opacity:0;" />
    @foreach(var filename in fileNames)
    {
        <MudChip Color="Color.Primary" Text="@filename" Size="Size.Small" OnClose="@(() => Closed(filename))"/>
    }
</MudPaper>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not usually use inline styles, but try putting the img in a div with a class name "container". Make it the same size as dash-lined container. Then you can use the code that I provided below in either or css file that connects to your document, or you could change it to an inline style.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```